# Ambiguous variadic class member access

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm just starting my journey into more advanced template code. Consider the following...

```
template <typename T>
class node_base
{
public:
    T member;

    node_base() {}

    void do_the_thing(node_base& other)
    {
        std::cout << other.member;
    }
};

template <typename ...Args>
class node : public node_base<Args>...
{
public:
    node() :node_base<Args>()...{}
};

int main()
{
    node<int> int_node;
    node<int, double> double_node;

    int_node.do_the_thing(double_node);

    double_node.do_the_thing(int_node); // ambiguous call

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2017 15.4.5, I get the following...

> error C2385: ambiguous access of 'do_the_thing' note: could be the
>   'do_the_thing' in base 'node_base'  note: or could be the
>   'do_the_thing' in base 'node_base'

My understanding is that the compiler should be able to deduce the correct function based on the argument, in this case `node<int>`. Why is this call considered ambiguous? What can I do to clarify the call while still maintaining this template pattern?

Comment: Can you add the complete compiler error message, including the extra lines (if any) about the function signatures the compiler considered?

Comment: Able to reproduce with gcc-6.4.0 and clang-6.0.0.  clang's error message is more helpful than gcc's: `template.cpp:31:17: error: member 'do_the_thing' found in multiple base classes of different types`

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Added

Comment: What is it supposed to do if you pass a `node<int, double>` to another `node<int, double>` or similar scenarios?

Comment: @super To be honest, I haven't thought that far ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about templates. You can reproduce it with the following:

```
struct A1 { void foo(); };
struct A2 { void foo(); };
struct B : A1, A2 {};
int main()
{
    B b;
    b.foo();
}
```

The relevant part of the Standard is

> **If the resulting set of declarations are not all from sub-objects of the same type**, or the set has a nonstatic member and includes members from distinct sub-objects, there is an ambiguity and the program is ill-formed.

So, you have two subobjects of types `node_base<int>` and `node_base<double>`.

EDIT: To address changes in the question and as DeanSeo deleted his solution, i will post it here:

```
template <typename T>
class node_base
{
public:
    T member = sizeof(T);
    node_base() {}

    void do_the_thing(node_base& other) {
        std::cout << other.member << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename ...Args>
class node : public node_base<Args>...
{
public:
    node() :node_base<Args>()...{}

    template <class T>
    void do_the_thing(node_base<T>& other) {
        node_base<T>::do_the_thing(other);
    }
};

int main()
{
    node<int> int_node;
    node<double, int> double_node;

    int_node.do_the_thing<int>(double_node);
    double_node.do_the_thing(int_node);

    double_node.do_the_thing<double>(double_node);
    double_node.do_the_thing<int>(double_node);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get that part. I've edited my question to include a request for a solution. I understand there may be a method to disambiguate the call with a `using` statement.

Comment: @JohnStritenberger i think you can go for DeanSeo solution. Though compiler will not be able to deduce proper type always, you can help him - [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce29cd262735605c)

Comment: To add my comment a bit here, as @RemyLebeau addressed, probably the OP will have to think about edge cases where a `node` with multiple template arguments takes another `node` with multiple template arguments and how they should be deduced to which type.
Otherwise the OP will have to explictely declare the desired type.

Comment: @JohnStritenberger Please read the clause 3 here [namespace.udecl](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl). It is C++17, so it is not implemented yet in most compilers, but in future it can help.